# Using the public keyword in static methods to access it from another class in C#

Tags: java, c#

Unlike Java,in C# why do we have to use the public keyword in static methods,variables to access it from another class? The following code gives compiler error:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
    A.say();    
    }
}

class A{
     static void say(){
     Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bunch of compiler errors, I'm sure. For `Main` to be recognized as the entry point of your program, it needs to be `public`. Yes, `say` needs to be public to be visible outside the class. Are you sure that's not the rule in Java as well? As you have written it, `say` is `private`, and as a result visible only within the class. And, as to why something is different in C# compared to Java, well, they are different languages. If you want to start a fight at a combined C#/Java conference, bring up exception specifications

Comment: I was wondering the same that how main is working without making it public.I only made the say method public now its working!

Comment: The 'Main' method is a special case, has numerous variations in C# (unlike the single allowed version in Java), and does not have to be public.

Answer (score 2):

Because [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers):

> Class and struct members, including nested classes and structs, have `private` access by default.

Presumably the compiler error you allude to (but don't specify) was telling you that the member is inaccessible due to its protection level.  That's because the default is `private` when not specified, and that member indeed does not specify.

Make the member `public` to access it from outside the class:

```
public static void say(){
    Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! didnt know that in C# the default is private when not specified.

Comment: If they are private by default,how is the Main working since i didnt make it public?

Comment: For 15+ years, I've assumed it had to be public. It turns out that it does not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/. I can check off my *You learn something new every day* box for today